# Когда может неверно сработать std::sort() или в чем ошибка

Tags: c++, сортировка

На вход подается множество строк. Необходимо распарсить его на слова и вывести в порядке убывания частоты упоминания слова (в случае равенства частоты для двух слов выводить их в лексикографическом порядке). 
Есть код, который на некоторых тестах работает правильно, а на некоторых падает (во время процедуры sort). Меня не интересует сейчас вопрос правильности или оптимизации решения, вопрос в том, почему программа вообще может упасть во время исполнения? Вроде бы одни стандартные решения, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться...

```
typedef pair<int, string> Ptype; //Pair_type

map<string, int> m; // m - map
vector<Ptype> v; // v - vector
string s;  // s - string


while(cin >> s)
{
    m[s]++;
}

for(auto& i: m)
    v.push_back({i.second, i.first});

/*here can be an error*/
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Ptype& a, const Ptype& b)
                    { return (a.first>b.first? true : a.second<b.second); } );

for(auto& i: v)
    cout << i.second << endl;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш предикат сравнения не удовлетворяет требованиям strict weak ordering.

Например, если у нас есть пары `{ 10, "a" }` и `{ 5, "b" }`, то ваш предикат сравнения будет всегда выдавать `true`, в каком бы порядке мы эти пары в него ни подавали. Корректный предикат сравнения не должен выдавать `true` одновременно  на оба сравнения `P(a, b)` и `P(b, a)`. Выдавать `false` на оба варианта можно, но ни в коем случае не `true`.

Сравнение между `a.second` и `b.second` можно делать только в том случае, когда `a.first == b.first`. А вы делаете это сравнение даже в случаях, когда `a.first < b.first`. Получается белиберда, поведение не определено, алгоритм сортировки падает.

Можно сделать так

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), 
     [](const Ptype& a, const Ptype& b)
       { return a.first != b.first ? a.first > b.first : a.second < b.second); });
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Если я правильно понял, с таким сравнением у меня отсутствует частичный порядок на множестве. Не подскажите, а как именно происходит падение sort() в данном случае? Он начинает зацикливаться?

Comment: @yataw: На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Что произойдет - зависит от деталей реализации `std::sort`. Может вообще не упасть, а просто "плохо" отсортировать. А может упасть и по зацикливанию, и по выходу за пределы диапазона, и по множеству других причин. В конце концов, в отладочной версии библиотеки может просто стоять `assert` на то, что предикат сравнения не возвращает `true` для обоих случаев.

Answer (score 0):

Вас не интересует оптимизация решения, но все же:

```
struct Cmp {
    using Ptype = pair<string, int> ;
    bool operator ()(const Ptype& a, const Ptype& b)
    { return a.second != b.second ? a.second > b.second : a.first < b.first; }
};    
int main()
{
    map<string, int> m;
    string s;
    while(cin >> s)
        m[s]++;
    set<Cmp::Ptype, Cmp> res(m.begin(), m.end());
    for (auto& p : res)
        cout << p.first << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

так лучше: нет цикла заполнения контейнера(в вашем случаи вектора, в моем - множества) и вызова альгоритма сортировки